# Displaying number of records from database

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I use something like this to delete records from database:

```
// did user press submit
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
// what button did they press
if ( isset( $_POST['delete'], $_POST['id']) ) {
    // we have been request to delete
    // and we have an id to control the delete

    // instantiate the class we need
    $cat = new Category($conn);

    // clean up our input before we us it in a SQL query
    $id = filter_input ( INPUT_POST , 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    // call the method we want to run
    $cat->deleteSelected($id);
}
}
?>


<form action="" method="post">
<label>Category id :</label>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" required="required" placeholder="Please     Enter Id"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete"/><br />
</form>
```

Now, what I want to do is to display number of records from a database with using this function:

```
 // countAll(): This function will count all the categories and return it.
public function countAll() {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM categories';

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    return $count;
}
```

What do I have to change in the first code (or also in second one) to make it displaying quantity of records in categories table after clicking a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply echo the result of countAll()

```
<?php
  echo countAll();

  public function countAll() {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM categories';

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    return $count;
 }
?>
```